# The intersection of a rational line and a rational cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I am trying to study rational points op elliptic curves of Tate and Silverman, but i don't understand one of the results.

Suppose we have a rational cubic in the form:

$ax^3 + bx^2y + cxy^2 + dy^3 + ex^2 + fxy+ gy^2 + hx + iy + j =0 \qquad a \dots j \in \mathbb{Q}$

and a rational line

$ax+by+c=0 \qquad a \dots c \in \mathbb{Q}$

Then one can find three intersections an the book states that if two of these intersections are rational, the third is too.

I don't seem to understand why this is necessarily true. any tips on how to see this?

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate $y$ to get a univariate rational cubic. Then the product of the tree roots is the ratio of the extreme coefficients, a rational number.

Algebraically,

$$x_2=\frac{ja'^3-c'ia'^2+gc'^2a'-dc'^3}{(aa'^3-bb'a'^2+b^2ca'-db'^3)x_0x_1},\\
y_2=-\frac{a'x_2+c'}{b'}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $y$ from $ax+by+c=0$ to the equation of general cubic, we will obtain a cubic equation in 1-variable of the form $Ax^3 +Bx^2 +Cx +D = 0$ whose two roots are known to be rational. The third root will be rational because sum of the roots of the above cubic equation is $\frac{-B}{A} \in \mathbb{Q}$.